# How can I activate quick actions in the mail message list in MS Outlook 2019

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2019

How can I enable quick actions - specifically the delete button - to show in the message list in Outlook 2019?

In Outlook 2016 this is definitely possible, but i cannot find how to enable this on 2019.

The screenshot below illustrates what i am looking for.

[image]

Screenshot on top from Outlook 2016 WITH delete Quick Action button showing. Screenshot on the bottom from Outlook 2019 where i would like the Quick Action button to show.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the second screenshot, it seems that you are using Touch Mode in which the Delete button is moved to the side bar:
[image]

Please switch back to Mouse mode and see the result. Here is a similar discussion in TechNet forum for your reference:
[Outlook 2013 (365 Home) Quick Delete "X" Button Missing](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/87f3fd52-3e3a-48a8-9971-e53f2715b024/outlook-2013-365-home-quick-delete-quotxquot-button-missing?forum=officeitpro)

Comment: Alt+M "Touch" shows the option to toggle between Touch mode and Mouse Mode. In Mouse mode the delete "X" is indeed shown in the message list.